# Best way to use custom enums in my plugin templates?

Tags: plugin-development, templating, controller, custom-field

I am building a plugin that's uses an enum for custom statuses. The statuses are integrated within my plugin with the exception of changing the status in my template code.

**pluginname/enums/PluginStatus.php**

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class PluginNameStatus
{
    const Approved = 'approved';
    const Denied   = 'denied';
    const Pending  = 'pending';
}
```

What is the best method to grab the enum values and display those in a select field for my edit template? All of my templates are rendered via controller actions so I am thinking that assigning the enums to an array and passing to the templates as $variables might be the most practical method.

**pluginname/controllers/PluginNameController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class PluginNameController extends BaseController
{
    public function actionShowIndex()
    {
        $variables['customStatuses'] = array(
            PluginStatus::Approved => 'Approved',
            PluginStatus::Denied   => 'Denied',
            PluginStatus::Pending  => 'Pending',
        ), 
        $this->renderTemplate('pluginname/_edit', $variables);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now that's probably the best way to do it.

For Craft 2.2, I just added a static `getConstants()` method to BaseEnum, so you can do can do a `PluginStatus::getConstants()` call that will return an array with a key => value pair of the enum options and their values that should make that cleaner.

Comment: Glad you're easily impressed. :)

Comment: Anything Brad does impresses me as I know getting you to do anything takes an act of God... ;)

But seriously, awesome to hear.

Answer (score 2):

I found an issue importing the enums via the `init()` method. You will receive a `Fatal error: Class 'Craft\PluginStatus' not found` on install. It seems during the install the `init()` method is not called in time to include the custom enums.

However, this works as its called immediately.

**pluginname/PluginNamePlugin.php**

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

// include enums for custom statuses
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/enums/PluginStatus.php');

class PluginNamePlugin extends BasePlugin
{
    // etc
}
```